# Bitwise operations in subleq

Tags: assembly, bitwise-operators, cpu-architecture

Many pages demonstrate synthesising more complicated arithmetic and logical operations out of the single [subleq](http://esolangs.org/wiki/subleq) instruction. I have not managed to find any pages discussing implementations of bitwise operations such as NAND, XOR ... Etc

Personally I haven't found a method that implements any of those operations (except for NOT) without using loops. Is there a neat way of doing it?

Comment: Not a real solution, but something to read for inspiration, is [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/) which has further references to various ways of implementing bitwise operations. There's also a paper [Bit Copying](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.2173.pdf) which uses loops by Oleg Mazonka who implemented the [HSQ](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Higher_Subleq) subset of C.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a little demonstration program. I did use loops to implement some of the operators.

```
"""
This program demonstrates that you can write the bit operators AND, OR and XOR
in terms of the subtract and branch if equal or lower (subleq) operator.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer

C.M. Punter 2016
"""
import random


def my_sub(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a - b


def my_leq(a: int, b: int) -> bool:
    return a <= b


# now we write all other functions in terms of the above two functions

def my_add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return my_sub(a, my_sub(0, b))


def my_mul(a: int, b: int) -> int:

    c = 0

    while my_leq(1, b):
        c = my_add(c, a)
        b = my_sub(b, 1)

    return c


def my_div(a: int, b: int) -> int:

    c = 0

    while my_leq(b, a):
        c = my_add(c, 1)
        a = my_sub(a, b)

    return c


def my_mod(a: int, b: int) -> int:

    while my_leq(b, a):
        a = my_sub(a, b)

    return a


def my_and(a: int, b: int) -> int:

    c = 0
    d = 1

    while my_leq(1, my_mul(a, b)):

        # we look at the first bit of a and b by checking if the number is odd or even
        # for this we use the modulo operator (a mod 2 and b mod 2)
        # this results in a 1 if the number is odd (which means the first bit is 1)
        # and 0 if the number is even (which means the first bit is 0)
        # multiplying those two numbers gives the and-operator for the first bit of a and b
        # the other bits are handled by bit-shifting a and b
        # this is equivalent to multiplying (left-shift) or dividing (right-shift) by 2

        c = my_add(c, my_mul(my_mul(my_mod(a, 2), my_mod(b, 2)), d))
        d = my_mul(d, 2)
        a = my_div(a, 2)
        b = my_div(b, 2)

    return c


def my_or(a: int, b: int) -> int:

    c = 0
    d = 1

    while my_leq(1, my_add(a, b)):
        if my_leq(1, my_add(my_mod(a, 2), my_mod(b, 2))):
            c = my_add(c, d)

        d = my_mul(d, 2)
        a = my_div(a, 2)
        b = my_div(b, 2)

    return c


def my_xor(a: int, b: int) -> int:

    c = 0
    d = 1

    while my_leq(1, my_add(a, b)):
        e = my_add(my_mod(a, 2), my_mod(b, 2))
        if my_leq(e, 1):
            c = my_add(c, my_mul(e, d))

        d = my_mul(d, 2)
        a = my_div(a, 2)
        b = my_div(b, 2)

    return c


def test(a: int, b: int):
    assert a & b == my_and(a, b)
    assert a | b == my_or(a, b)
    assert a ^ b == my_xor(a, b)

for i in range(1000):
    test(random.randint(0, 1024), random.randint(0, 1024))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a more efficient way of doing this, this requires the use of looping operators and the construction of a less than (but not equal to) zero function, which you will have to provide yourself. The idea is that you can check a single bit (the top bit) for it being negative, you can then use this to construct an OR, AND or XOR.

```
/* Author: Richard James Howe
 * Email:  howe.r.j.89@gmail.com 
 * Using primitives available in SUBLEQ to perform bitwise operations */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N   (16)
#define TST (9999)

typedef int16_t uword_t;
typedef int16_t  word_t;

static uword_t zlt(uword_t z) {
    return ((word_t)z) < 0 ? 0xFFFFu : 0;
}

static uword_t add(uword_t a, uword_t b) {
    return a - (uword_t)((uword_t)0 - b);
}

static uword_t lshift1(uword_t a) {
    return add(a, a);
}

static uword_t b_or(uword_t a, uword_t b) {
    uword_t r = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        r = lshift1(r);
        if ((uword_t)(zlt(a) + zlt(b)) != (uword_t)0u)
            r++;
        a = lshift1(a);
        b = lshift1(b);
    }
    return r;
}

static uword_t b_xor(uword_t a, uword_t b) {
    uword_t r = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        r = lshift1(r);
        if ((uword_t)(zlt(a) + zlt(b)) == (uword_t)0xFFFFu)
            r++;
        a = lshift1(a);
        b = lshift1(b);
    }
    return r;
}

static uword_t b_and(uword_t a, uword_t b) {
    uword_t r = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        r = lshift1(r);
        if ((uword_t)(zlt(a) + zlt(b)) == (uword_t)0xFFFEu)
            r++;
        a = lshift1(a);
        b = lshift1(b);
    }
    return r;
}

static uword_t rnd(void) {
    return rand();
}

int main(void) {
    int pass_or = 1, pass_xor = 1, pass_and = 1;
    for (long i = 0; i < TST; i++) {
        uword_t a = rnd(), b = rnd();
        uword_t rn = a | b;
        uword_t rb = b_or(a, b);
        if (rb != rn) {
            printf("or fail %x %x -- expected %x got %x\n", a, b, rn, rb);
            pass_or = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("or %s\n", pass_or ? "pass" : "FAIL");
    for (long i = 0; i < TST; i++) {
        uword_t a = rnd(), b = rnd();
        uword_t rn = a ^ b;
        uword_t rb = b_xor(a, b);
        if (rb != rn) {
            printf("xor fail %x %x -- expected %x got %x\n", a, b, rn, rb);
            pass_xor = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("xor %s\n",  pass_xor ? "pass" : "FAIL");
    for (long i = 0; i < TST; i++) {
        uword_t a = rnd(), b = rnd();
        uword_t rn = a & b;
        uword_t rb = b_and(a, b);
        if (rb != rn) {
            printf("and fail %x %x -- expected %x got %x\n", a, b, rn, rb);
            pass_and = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("and %s\n",  pass_and ? "pass" : "FAIL");
    printf("done %s\n", pass_or && pass_xor && pass_and ? "pass" : "FAIL");
    return 0;
}
```

See also:

- https://gist.github.com/howerj/a08b127e944df30deaf0a4fec1a6d5be (where this code come from)
- https://github.com/howerj/subleq (a usage of this code for a Forth interpreter)
- https://gist.github.com/howerj/4e0741370bd22b3181443bf3e0ba6697 (for implementing the comparison operators)

Comment: Isn't `((word_t)z) < 0` a less-than rather than less-or-equal operation?  I guess there's some well-known way to implement that and `== 0xFFFEu` in terms of `subleq`, but you don't mention it in your answer.

Comment: Yes, it is, you have to implement that yourself, equality and inequality are fairly easy to implement, so are looping, most SUBLEQ assemblers already implement such constructs. So I left them out. However, less than zero (and not equal to) is a little more tricky, but it is possible. I'll get around to adding "< 0".

Comment: I've just added a gist for the comparison operators, so you can see how they are implemented.